# How can I select the p-value of the weak instruments test in r?

Tags: r, lm

When I calculate a linear model with `ivreg` then I get the p-value for the weak instruments test with `summary(iv_model1)`

```
Diagnostic tests:
                 df1 df2 statistic  p-value    
Weak instruments   1 367     53.56 2.23e-12 ***
```

How can I get the p-value alone? Like I can get the Intercept of the model with the command `iv_model1$coefficients[1]`
I went through `str(iv_model1)` but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Your example isn't something I can run to test this, but I'd guess the p-value would be returned as part of `summary(iv_model1)`.  Often (but unfortunately not always) `summary()` functions return the values that they print.  So look at `str(summary(iv_model1))`.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you more. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg